# AOC 21" monitor wont' wake up after computer goes to sleep

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display, mini-displayport

I have a dual monitor setup. An AOC 21" monitor to accompany my iMac. After waking the iMac from sleep, the AOC monitor doesn't wake up without me having to unplug the dvi cable from the monitor and plug it back in.This is pretty annoying. Since i'm using an iMac, i have to use a dvi-to-minidisplay converter, so i'm wondering it that responsible for this behavior.

Has anybody who has been experiencing the same behavior with their additional monitor been able to find a workaround for this? AOC has no drivers for the mac. So i'm running out of ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: Did you tried this with any other models other than the AOC?.

Comment: Yes, I had a 17-inch samsung monitor that didn't give me any trouble.

Comment: seems to be a compatibility issue